# Pull specific value from JSON but: TypeError: list indices must be integers not str

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

> This is the JSON output from the API

```
{
"list":[
    {
          "dt": 1490791600,
          "temp": {
              "day": 58.26,
              "min": 39.65,
              "max": 67.37
          }
          "weather":  [
               {
                   "id": 500,
                   "main":  "Rain",
                   "description": "light rain",
                   "icon": "10d"
                }
     ]
     {
          "dt": 1480878000,
          "temp": {
              "day": 57.34,
              "min": 40.11,
              "max": 68.23
          }
          "weather":  [
               {
                   "id": 501,
                   "main":  "Showers",
                   "description": "possible rain",
                   "icon": "11d"
                }
     ]
  ]
```

}

> This is my code.  I want to try and pull the "id" for all of the weather dates.

```
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)

data = json.load(json_obj)

for item in data['list']:

    temperature = item['temp']['min']
    forecast = item['weather']['main']
```

> I am able to pull the temperature data without an issue but I get a TypeError:  list indices must be integers not str  when I try and pull the forecast data.  I'm thinking this is due to list vs dictionary concepts.  How can I pull the "id" values from this JSON data?

Comment: forecast = item['weather'][0]['main']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`weather` is a list of 1 element. So you should access the data in the following way. 
 
`forecast = item['weather'][0]['main']`